# LED status light

Tags: notification-led, sony-xperia-z2

The light at the top of my phone is always flashing various colours. How do I know what they mean and how do I turn them off? It's Kitkat on Xperia Z2.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the default colours are, but with an app called "Light Flow" on Google Play, you can change & add colours for almost any app or notification, or indeed turn all off as you are looking to do.

Answer (score -1):

Navigate here. 
Settings - Display - Light effects. 
You can find various options on LED flashing.

Comment: mine doesn't have "light effects" it only has a check box for "notification light"